# Specifying colors for specific text-decorations

Tags: css

I'm working on updating my tumblr theme, and I want to make it so that if text has the text-decoration:line-through property, it instead has color: white. I want to be able to use this to hide spoilers. Is there a way to do that? Make it so that an item has a certain property ONLY if it has another property?

Comment: I don't think that's possible with pure CSS. You can use JavaScript to first select all such elements and filter them according to their CSS properties. Or you can define a CSS class which you can apply to your desired elements.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with the [Attribute Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

```
[attr*=value]
```

> Represents elements with an attribute name of attr whose value
> contains at least one occurrence of value within the string.

Here an example

```css
[style*="line-through"] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
Text <span style="text-decoration: line-through;">turns red when line-through</span>
```